# Как проверить отправляющийся Model с текстом на jsp странице

Tags: jstl, java

Мне никак не дойдет как проверить отправляющийся `Model` с текстом на `jsp` странице.
Контроллер:

```
model.addAttribute("issuance", "true");
```

И как на jsp странице проверить что храни в себе `${issuance}`
пробовал:

```
<c:if test="${issuance == 'true'}">
```

не срабатывает. Не нагуглил, и ума не приложу как оно должно быть.

Comment: См. в сторону скриптлета типа: `request.getAttribute("issuance");`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Не понимаю в чем проблема, если Вы добавляете аттрибут в модель и он без тегов,то будет просто как текст отображаться. Или Вы хотите проверить, срабатывает ли вообще передача?

model.addAttribute("issuance", "true"); 
Просто вставит этот кусок в Ваш html, обращаться к нему не получится, как мне кажется.

Comment: Мне нужно проверить, действительно ли в issuance == 'true'